# Как следует писать: подробности чего или подробности о чем?

Tags: управление

Как следует писать: подробности чего или подробности о чем?

В Национальном корпусе русского языка вхождений в первом варианте примерно на три порядка больше, чем во втором.

Может быть, в каком-нибудь словаре управления указана норма?

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, оба варианта допустимы. Вариант "подробности чего-либо" описан в словарях. Вариант "подробности о/об/обо чем-либо" встречатся 836+153+11 раз в Нацкорпусе и подтвержден ответами Грамоты.

> Вопрос № 256458
>   Корректна ли фраза "Узнайте подробнее о сервисе".
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Корректно, но лучше: узнайте подробности (или в подробностях) о сервисе.
>
> Вопрос № 211105
>   Как правильно писать: "подробности о новом альбоме группы ХХХ" или "подробности нового альбома группы ХХХ"? "подробности о семинаре" или "подробности семинара"?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Если речь идёт о сведениях об альбоме и семинаре, корректно: *подробности об альбоме, подробности о семинаре*.

Answer (score 3):

Выбрать падеж можно путем грамматического анализа. Рассмотрим **два варианта**: *подробности происшествия  и подробности о происшествии*.

**Подробности (какие) происшествия:** беспредложное управление Р.п., определительное значение (как и что происходило, перечень событий).

**Подробности о происшествии:** изъяснительное значение предлога О (само происшествие, слухи о нем, сообщения в СМИ и др.).

**Примеры:**

Свидетели рассказали **подробности происшествия**.

Каждый день к нам на улице подходил кто-нибудь и рассказывал новые **подробности о происшествии.**